# C# - Listview colum header height (Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, listview

How can I change the height of the column header in a ListView ?

(visual studio-2008,windows forms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy but it can be done.

The basic strategy is to get the underlying header control from the `ListView` (using LVM_GETHEADER message), setup a `NativeWindow` instance on that control, and then listen for HDM_LAYOUT messages. In that message, you can specify the location and size of the header.

As the author of [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) mentioned above, I have to say it's much easier to let someone else do all this work for you. ObjectListView uses dynamic header height to allow multiline headers and vertical text, like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) it supports a lot of customizations and you might find in there the way how to do it as it is open source.